# How to get path in spring to access configuration file

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I have written a Spring program where the following classes, interfaces and xml files are in different packages. I use Eclipse Kepler.

[image: file structure]

#### SelectClient.java

```
package com.rajeev.spring.action;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

import com.rajeev.spring.DAOI.Select;

/**
 * @author rajeev
 *
 * 
 */
public class SelectClient {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path=System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.out.println(path+"/src/com/rajeev/spring/DAOImpl/SelectCfg.xml");
        Resource resource=new ClassPathResource(path+"/src/com/rajeev/spring/DAOImpl/SelectCfg.xml");
        XmlBeanFactory beanFactory=new XmlBeanFactory(resource);
        Object object=beanFactory.getBean("sb");
        Select select=(Select)object;
        System.out.println("emp name is:"+select.fetchName(101));
    }

}
```

The problem is that when I execute the `SelectClient.java`, it is giving following error

```
E:\javahyd\eclipse\Spring_DataSource_Object_Inject/src/com/rajeev/spring/DAOImpl/SelectCfg.xml
Jan 17, 2014 11:41:43 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [E:/javahyd/eclipse/Spring_DataSource_Object_Inject/src/com/rajeev/spring/DAOImpl/SelectCfg.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [E:/javahyd/eclipse/Spring_DataSource_Object_Inject/src/com/rajeev/spring/DAOImpl/SelectCfg.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [E:/javahyd/eclipse/Spring_DataSource_Object_Inject/src/com/rajeev/spring/DAOImpl/SelectCfg.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.(XmlBeanFactory.java:78)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.(XmlBeanFactory.java:66)
    at com.rajeev.spring.action.SelectClient.main(SelectClient.java:26)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [E:/javahyd/eclipse/Spring_DataSource_Object_Inject/src/com/rajeev/spring/DAOImpl/SelectCfg.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    ... 4 more
```

The above exception, is due to the path. When I use the same path in run(windows+r) the particular file it is opening. I dont want to keep my configuration file out of any packages.

Comment: @MagicMan not working

Comment: Try this: `Resource resource=new ClassPathResource("com/rajeev/spring/DAOImpl/SelectCfg.xml");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClassPathResource` is used to refer the path of the resource in the classpath. The `path` argument passed in the `ClassPathResource` refers to the absolute path within the class path.So, use

```
Resource resource=new ClassPathResource("com/rajeev/spring/DAOImpl/SelectCfg.xml");
```

Try to use `FileSystemResource` to mention absolute path in the filesystem

Comment: I wrote this                                                          String path=System.getProperty("user.dir");
  System.out.println(path+"/src/com/rajeev/spring/DAOImpl/SelectCfg.xml");

Answer (score -1):

Use FileSystemResource  instead of ClassPathResource resource and give complete path e.g `Resource resource=new FileSystemResource("C://path/to//your//config.xml");`

Comment: Simply do `new FileSystemResource("C:/path/to/your/config.xml");`, without the double forward slash will be all right, I validated it on Windows 7. If you have to use double slash for some reason, use the backslash will make it work too, I also validated/tested it on Windows 7. Just like so `new FileSystemResource("C:\\path\\to\\your\\config.xml");`